# How to calculate average delay time of circuit having several possible transition states

Tags: xilinx, delay, time, cadence

[image]Is it possible to calculate average delay for all possible states directly without calculating them individually using Xilinx or with Cadence.

Comment: What type of circuit do you have in mind? Also picture would help.

Comment: This is pretty close: "Run the Place & Route process with the Generate Asynchronous Delay Report property enabled in the Place & Route Properties dialog box." It will list 20 nets with the longest delays.

Comment: Generally, the only important value is the *worst case* propagation delay. What do you want to do with the *average*?

Comment: I have seen in many ieee papers stating that average delay of the circuit,i just wonder how they are able to calculate average delay.